# Find $\angle ABC$ in the triangle below,

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In a $\triangle ABC$, draw the heights $AP$ and $CQ$ and the interior angle bisector $BD$. Calculate $ m \angle ABC$, knowing that:$\dfrac{1}{AP}+\dfrac{1}{CQ} = \dfrac{2}{BD}$
(Answer provided: $30^o$)

I try:

$\dfrac{AD}{AB} = \dfrac{CD}{BC}$

$AC^2=AQ^2+CQ^2 \implies CQ^2 = AC^2-AQ^2$

$BC^2 = CQ^2+BQ^2 \implies BC^2 = AC^2-AQ^2+BQ^2$

$AB^2 = AD^2+BD^2 \implies BD^2=AB^2-AD^2$

$BC^2=BD^2+CD^2 \implies BC^2 = AB^2-AD^2+CD^2$

[image]

Comment: Using the law of sines, I get that angle $B=60^ \circ$

Comment: @Lozenges Please post your solution. There is the alternative of $60ô$ in the question. It may be that the given answer is wrong

Comment: @Lozenges By Geogebra , answer is $60^o$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $a=BC, b=AC, c=AB, 2x =\angle ABC$.
Use the law of sines in triangle $BAD$

$$\frac{A D}{\sin  x}=\frac{B D}{\sin  A}=\frac{B D}{C Q/b}$$

Similarly, in triangle $BCD$

$$\frac{C D}{\sin  x}=\frac{B D}{\sin  C}=\frac{B D}{A P/b}$$

Add

$$\frac{b}{\sin  x}=\frac{\text{AD} + \text{CD}}{\sin  x}=\frac{A D}{\sin  x}+\frac{C D}{\sin  x}=\frac{B D}{C Q/b}+\frac{B D}{A P/b}= BD \left( \frac{b}{\text{CQ}}+\frac{b}{\text{AP}}\right)=2 b $$

$$\sin  x=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$x=30^{\circ} $$

$$\angle ABC = 60^{\circ}$$

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on my comment on [sirious](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/346566/sirous) **erroneous** answer, the triangle in OP **must not be equilateral**.

In fact the correct answer above by [Lozenges](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/219277/lozenges) shows that **a necessary and sufficient condition is that the bisected angle measure is $60^\circ$**.

To further emphasize this point, we can easily prove that, provided that $\measuredangle ABC = 60^\circ$, the internal bisector of this angle is the harmonic mean of the altitudes w.r.t. sides $AB$ and $BC$ (the converse of what stated by OP).
Consider the figure below, where $CS\parallel BN$ and $BT\perp CS$.

[image]

Let now $\measuredangle ABC = 60^\circ$, $\overline{AH} = x$, $\overline{CK} = y$ and $\overline{BN} = z$.

We then have $\overline{AB} = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}x$, and $\overline{BC} = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} y$.

Since $\triangle BCS$ is isosceles with $\measuredangle CBS = 120^\circ$, we also have $\overline{BS} = \frac{2}{\sqrt 3} y$, and $\overline{CS} = 2y$.

Similarity $\triangle ABN \sim \triangle ASC$ yields
$$\frac{z}{2y}=\frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}x}{\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}x+\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}y}$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{2}{z} = \frac1x + \frac1y.$$

(In the figure above I took $\overline{AH} = 2$ and $\overline{BK}= 3$, so that $\overline{BN} = \frac{12}5$.)

---

As a final note, the above construction can be used, of course, to give an alternative proof of OP, **without trigonometric expressions**, as follows.

Suppose we have $$\frac{2}{z} = \frac1x+\frac1y.\tag{1}\label{1}$$

1. Similarity $\triangle ABH \sim \triangle BCK$ gives $\overline{AB} = kx$ and $\overline{BC} = ky$, for some positive $k$.
2. The fact that $\triangle CBS$ is isosceles and similarity $\triangle ABN \sim \triangle ACS$ yields $$\frac{z}{kx} = \frac{\overline{CS}}{kx+ky},$$ that is $$z = \frac{x\cdot \overline{CS}}{x+y}.\tag{2}\label{2}$$
3. From \eqref{1} we have $$z = \frac{2xy}{x+y}\tag{3}\label{3}.$$
4. Comparing \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} leads to $$\overline{CS} = 2y,$$ that is $$\overline{CT} = y.$$
5. By HL congruence $\triangle BCK \cong \triangle BCT$. Hence $$\angle ABC \cong \angle CBT \cong \angle TBS.$$ Therefore $$\boxed{\measuredangle ABC = 60^\circ}.$$

Comment: Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Comment: In equilateral triangle we have:

$\frac1 s+\frac 1 s=\frac 2s$

where  s is the area of triangle. We write this relation in terms of altitudes and sides:

$\frac 1 {ah_a}+\frac 1 {ch_c}=\frac 2 {bh_b}$

$a=b=c$

therefore:

$\frac 1{h_a}+\frac 1{h_c}=\frac 2{h_b}$

which is given relation in statement if BD is also the altitude of the triangle.. Hence triangle must be equilateral and we must have $\angle ABC=60^o$

Comment: How do you draw such conclusion? You proved that if the triangle is equilateral then the relationship in OP holds. Not the the converse!

Comment: @dfnu, Method of comparison is some thing usual in mathematics. For example in algebra we sometimes compare two equations to find the solution. This is what I did and cocluded that BD must also be altitude .

Comment: That doesn't make sense. When you solve an equation, in fact, you write *equivalences*. That's absolutely not what you did here. There's a great difference between necessary and sufficient conditions. What you call "method of comparison" isn't clear at all (-1).

Comment: Please have a look below at a triangle which satisfies OP's conditions but **is not equilateral** and take some time to modify your misleading reply. Your argument is clearly circular, since at the beginning you assume the triangle is equilateral. So **of course** the internal bisector coincides with the altitude.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the figure, draw $DX$, $DY$ perpendicular to $BC$ and $BA$ as shown.

$(1)  \Delta BDX \cong \Delta BDY \implies DX=DY.$

$(2)  \Delta ADY \sim \Delta ACQ \implies \frac{DY}{CQ}=\frac{AD}{AC}.$

$(3)  \Delta CDX \sim \Delta CAP \implies \frac{DX}{AP}= \frac{CD}{AC}.$

$(4)$ From $(1), (2), (3)$, we have
$$\frac{DY}{CQ}+\frac{DX}{AP}=\frac{AD}{AC}+\frac{CD}{AC}$$
$$\frac{DX}{CQ}+\frac{DX}{AP}=\frac{AD+CD}{AC}$$
$$\frac{DX}{CQ}+\frac{DX}{AP}=1$$
$$\frac{1}{CQ}+\frac{1}{AP}=\frac{1}{DX}$$

$(5)$ Since it is given that $$\frac{1}{CQ}+\frac{1}{AP}=\frac{2}{BD}$$

$(6)$  $$\therefore \frac{1}{DX}=\frac{2}{BD}$$
$$\frac{DX}{BD}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sin \left( \frac{B}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{B}{2}=30^{\text o}$$
$$B=60^{\text o}$$